# Custom Collection returns first element empty

Tags: c#, generics, collections

I'm trying to recreate the generic List collection. This is my code to Add items to the collection and Show all of them:

```
public class Collect<TItem>
{
    public Collect<TItem> collectObject;
    public TItem firstObject;

    public void Add(TItem item)
    {
        if (collectObject == null)
        {
            collectObject = new Collect<TItem>();
            collectObject.firstObject = item;
        }
        else 
        {
            this.collectObject.Add(item);
        }
    }

    public void Show()
    {
        if (firstObject != null)
            Console.WriteLine(firstObject.ToString());

        if (collectObject != null)
            collectObject.Show();           
    }
```

You'd use this class like this:

```
Collect<int> test = new Collect<int>();
        test.Add(2);
        test.Add(10);
        test.Add(30);
        test.Add(3);
        test.Show();
```

It prints all of the values above, but the first item is always 0.

```
0
2
10
30
3
```

This is because the very first `firstObject` variable is never assigned and gets the default value, but I can't figure out a way to get this fixed. The book I learned this assigns the first `firstObject` variable in a constructor that expects a `TItem` object, but I want to do it without using a constructor for this collection (to recreate a List)

I know this is exactly the same like how a generic List works, but I just want to understand the logic behind it. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1):

You can make your TItem nullable, which allows your test to work. Also, you need to set the firstObject in the top instance of Collect, not the referenced one.

```
public class Collect<TItem> where TItem : struct
{
    public Collect<TItem> collectObject;
    public TItem? firstObject;

    public void Add(TItem item)
{
        if (collectObject == null)
        {
            collectObject = new Collect<TItem>();
            firstObject = item;
        }
        else 
        {
            this.collectObject.Add(item);
        }
    }

    public void Show()
    {
        if (firstObject.HasValue)
            Console.WriteLine(firstObject.ToString());

        if (collectObject != null)
            collectObject.Show();           
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What you doing wrong is `collectObject.firstObject = item;` should be `this.firstObject = item;`

Comment: Doing that will quickly get you a `StackOverflowException` with the OP's class design, as you try to create an infinite nest of `Collect<TItem>` objects.

Comment: Your edit just shifts the phantom value to the end of the output sequence rather than the beginning: `{2,10,30,3,0}` instead of `{0,2,10,30,3}`.

Answer (score 0):

OK, this is doing my head in, but I think you want to do something like:

```
if (collectObject == null)
    {
        collectObject = new Collect<TItem>();
        this.firstObject = item;
    }
```

because otherwise you are never actually assigning anythign tothe firstobject property of the object you are creating.

Comment: this.firstobject, rather than collectObject.firstObject. A critical difference.

Comment: That was pretty much what I thought but the more I read the code the less sense it makes as given what is posted I can't see how it prints anything other than 2. Edit - looks like I was wrong about it only printing 2...your change is correct tho.

Comment: @Schroedingers Cat: Ah ok, missed that. Although all your modification will do is change the output sequence to be `{2,10,30,3,0}` instead.

Comment: That is why it was doing my head in. There are more issues with the code but the answer to the question is to use this. not collectObject.

Answer (score 0):

I think you just have to change the line: 
collectObject.firstObject = item; 
to
firstObject = item;

This way your custom collection will always be represented by a "head" and a "tail" - I assume this is what you are tryin' to acomplish.

In other words when adding an item, you say "If this is the first time to add, then this is my 'head' of the list, else - insert it into the 'tail' of the list". Printing is with the same idea - print the "head" and then call the tail's print method (in your code 'Show' method).

Answer (score 0):

First, this is certainly not how `System.Collections.Generic.List<T>` works. It uses an array internally, not a singly-linked list as you do. `LinkedList<T>` is somewhat similar to your collection, except it uses a doubly liked list.

Now, onto your issue. The problem with your collection is that it is not able to represent an empty value and it seems you want that. What I would suggest is to create another public class that represents the whole collection and change your `Collect<T>` only to an internal implementation (let's call it `Node<T>`). This way, the new collection class can contain `null` reference to `Node<T>`, when it is first constructed, which signifies an empty collection.

If this were production code, I'm pretty sure you would actually need to do something like this, because you are going to want to keep some information on a per-collection basis (like count).

Another option (which is usually taken by lists in functional languages) is to create an inheritance hierarchy similar to the following:

```
abstract class Node<T>
{ }

class FullNode<T> : Node<T>
{
    public T Item { get; private set; }
    public Node<T> Next { get; private set }

    // constructor and possibly other members
}

class EmptyNode<T> : Node<T>
{ }
```

This way, you have separate types to represent a full node and an empty node. In those lists, it is usual to add new items to the front, not to the back, though.

I would suggest at least one other improvement, regarding the speed of adding, but I suppose your book will get to that.

Also, I'm quite sure this is the case, but I really hope you're not planning on using this code in any kind of production environment and that it is just an learning exercise.

Answer (score 0):

Just to add a little bit more information...

The reason the 0 is being written out is because you have a != null check on the firstObject.  Obviously, the default value of an integer is not null, it is zero, so when firstObject hasn't been set it will be zero and not null.  I guess if you want to exclude any value that is not the default for that type you could change your check to:

```
if (firstObject != default(TItem))
```

That's probably not exactly what you want though as I'm sure zero could be a valid value in this instance.

Answer (score 0):

Try a nullable type

```
Collect<int?> test = new Collect<int?>();
```